# CS:GO Server on OS X 10.9 Server

Tags: macos, counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

I'm wondering whether its possible to run a CSGO casual server on OS X Server for me and a few mates, the system is up to it hardware wise I'm just wondering if its actually possible and how it would be done. Only say 10 slots.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Notice: I haven't tested this on Mac OSX server but it should run.*

1. First [download and install SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Downloading_SteamCMD) and then start the programm.
2. Choose the path where the dedicated server should be installed with the `force_install_dir /full/path/to/csgo-ds/`command.
3. Install the dedicated server with this command: `app_update 740 validate`
4. Then quit the SteamCMD with `quit`.

---

After the server has been installed you can start him with one of these commands. Each one presents another game mode.

**Classic Casual**
`srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_bomb +map de_dust`
The last parameter represents the map that should be loaded.

**Classic Competitive**
`srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 1 +mapgroup mg_bomb_se +map de_dust2_se`

**Arms Race**
`srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 1 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_armsrace +map ar_shoots`

**Demolition**
`srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 1 +game_mode 1 +mapgroup mg_demolition +map de_lake`

**Deathmatch**
`srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 1 +game_mode 2 +mapgroup mg_allclassic +map de_dust`

---

You can edit the gamemodes and rules in the following two config files inside the */csgo/* folder:

- `gamemodes.txt` (Settings for all game modes)
- `gamemodes_server.txt` (Settings for all game modes)
- `gamemode_armsrace_server.cfg` (Settings for Arms Race mode)
- `server.cfg` (Servername, password, etc.)

Detailed infos about the different settings can be found in the full tutorial

---

**>>> Full tutorial [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers).**

Comment: Please summarize the instructions here.  That way, if the site ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it saves people a click.

Comment: @Frank Would make no sense as you have to download additional software directly from this website (powered by Valve directly). No need for an downvote, dude.

Comment: @Frank Better now?

Comment: Kovah, the increase in quality of this answer was so great that going back through my recent downvotes to check for updates, I thought the system led me to the wrong answer. Very good improvement! Keep up the good work and enjoy your time at Arqade!

Comment: I can confirm that this DOES work on Mac OS X 10.9.

Comment: I get error `ERROR! Failed to install app '740' (Invalid platform)` on mac. Same results ever after force setting the platform type to macos `@sSteamCmdForcePlatformType macos`. Setting platform to linux, does downloads the server, but server doesn't starts (see my comment on @Rüdiger answer). @Andrew did you got same errors ? if no, what macos you're using ?

Answer (score 2):

Before you type `app_update 740 validate` use `@sSteamCmdForcePlatformType linux` to allow for the Cross-Platform commands.

I set up steamcmd to make a CSGO server. I logged in anonymously and then did:

```
 Steam> force_install_dir csgo
```

after

```
 Steam> app_update 740 validate
```

I got

```
 ERROR! Failed to install app "740" (Invalid platform)
```

To prevent this, allow cross platform commands by entering

```
 Steam> @sSteamCmdForcePlatformType linux
```

Comment: This also didn't worked for me on mac. I get following error `./srcds_run: line 336: ./srcds_linux: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: even setting platformType to macos also didn't worked. See my comment on @Kovah's answer.